# Debian 9 give User permission for all folders

Tags: debian, file-permissions, user-permissions

How can I give a user permissions for all folders? So /home, /var etc.

Comment: Do you have very strong reason to do this? Because it is VERY insecure. And what kind of permissions we talk about?

Comment: What about this is insecure? Root has all permissions as well. I'm talking about being able to Upload Files, Edit Files, Remove Files **everywhere** without using sudo, because my SFTP Program doesn't support something like this

Comment: Use terminal and do the things locally. Upload in some temporary directory and the login with terminal and do the work.

Comment: But I don't want to do login everytime just to move a file which I uploaded in some folder.

Comment: Why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: Is it so hard to just answer a question? I know that this is considered to be unsafe, but I have my reasons for it.

Comment: This site is for _professional_ IT, and doing things that are unsafe is not something we wish to encourage. It's not just about you; many other people will read this question and should not be encouraged to develop bad habits. If you actually do have a really good reason for it, then it needs to be disclosed.

Comment: @OfficialCRUGG is this question answered, or is there anything unclear?

Answer (score 0):

To give a user (e.g. bob) read-permission for all folder in the /tmp/myfiles-directory:

1.) install `acl`:

`sudo apt-get install acl` (after running `apt-get update`)

2.) give the user "bob" read-permission for eveything in (and including) the `/tmp/myfiles`-directory:

`setfacl -m user:bob:r -R /tmp/myfiles`

3.) view the permissions on /tmp/myfiles with:

`getfacl /tmp/myfiles`

---

*To answer the specific case of giving read/write/execute-permissions to everything (although: **DONT EVER DO this!!!**) 
set eveything inside root to 
`setfacl -m user:bob:rwx -R /`*